# Controller do not receive values passed from json.stringify(obj)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am not understand this case:

I have a **model** like:

```
public class ExmDescobertos {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ExameId { get; set; }
    public int PlanoId { get; set; }
    public int ConvenioId { get; set; }
}
```

And create an **object javascript**:

```
var objDescoberto = new Object();
objDescoberto.Id = $("#hdnDescobertoId").val(); //inputs with values...
objDescoberto.ExameId = $('#hdnExameId').val();
objDescoberto.PlanoId = $('#hdnPlanoId').val();
objDescoberto.ConvenioId = $('#hdnConvenioId').val();
```

And I am using **Json.stringify(obj)** to transmit the values with a **$.post jQuery** method:

```
var dados = JSON.stringify(objDescoberto);
```

In this point, **dados** is *"{"Id":"27","ExameId":"53","PlanoId":"32","ConvenioId":"11"}"*, for example.

And have a controller with this action:

```
public PartialViewResult(ExmDescobertos descoberto) { }
```

But... the parameter in this controller not receive your values correct! :o
In this point **descoberto** is *Id = 0; ExameId = 0; PlanoId = 0; ConvenioId = 0;*

Not errors explicit, but not works... 
Anybody have a idea of what I have missing?
Thank you for all!

Comment: Can you use the browser's developer tools or Fiddler to see what the browser is actually sending?

Comment: How do you send that data? I mean can you post the javascript that makes the ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `stringify` you object, just send object as is.

```
$.post("/url", objDescoberto);
```

or

```
var dados = JSON.stringify({descoberto : objDescoberto});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ilya. Now, all wokrs vine. Great! ;)